# Restarting services after Capistrano Rails deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, capistrano, delayed-job

I have my site being deployed with Capistrano.  How can I get delayed_job and elasticsearch to restart after the deploy is complete?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create `delayed_job.rake` in `lib/capistrano/tasks`

```rb
# delayed_job.rake
namespace :delayed_job do
  def args
    fetch(:delayed_job_args, '')
  end

  def delayed_job_roles
    fetch(:delayed_job_server_role, :app)
  end

  desc 'Stop the delayed_job process'
  task :stop do
    on roles(delayed_job_roles) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :bundle, :exec, :'bin/delayed_job -n 1', :stop
        end
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Start the delayed_job process'
  task :start do
    on roles(delayed_job_roles) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :bundle, :exec, :'bin/delayed_job -n 1', args, :start
        end
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart the delayed_job process'
  task :restart do
    on roles(delayed_job_roles) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :bundle, :exec, :'bin/delayed_job -n 1', args, :restart
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and in your config/deploy.rb add the following lines

```rb
after :publishing, :restart

task :restart do
  invoke 'delayed_job:restart'
end
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.  Will that do ElasticSearch too?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much the same

Comment: I've just tried it but it doesn't seem to restart ES like you said?

Comment: Did you add another rake for your es? You should follow the same thing you did for your dj

Comment: But you said the above would do ES too? I'm confused.  Will it or won't it?  Can you please provide an example that will do both?

Comment: The above example is just for the `delayed_job`. If you want to restart other service like ES, you have to create a rake file and invoke it inside your capistrano deploy.rb.